# IOS Push notification smartface 4.3 registration and remote token

Tags: ios, notifications, push, smartface.io

I have include following code to smartface test application and exported to Xcode also emulator but  it alert empty result and ask any permission for push nitification.

```
Notifications.remote.registerForPushNotifications({
    OnSuccess : function () {
        alert("Success");
    },
    OnFailure : function () {
        alert("Fail");
    }
});
alert(Notifications.remote.token);
```

Seems it does not functioning Push notification. Is there any more setting to get access token of device? annd register for push notification?

Answer (score 2):

For parse notification `Notifications.remote.token` is a new feature which gives you the deviceToken value. With the next release, you will be able to use it.

But for GCM push, it should work with publish. Note that, with emulator it won't work.
Please be sure that you entered Sender ID value in Project Details. You can find this value from Overview section in console.developers.google. It will be given as Project Number.

Comment: is there any parameter to fetch device token?

Comment: also push notification registration woks with IOS?